# Drupal7. url from hook menu (and other) not work

Tags: php, drupal

Hi I have a old installation of Drupal 7 with some different subdomain

in the implement of hook menu we have some items like this

```
    $items['my-url'] = array(
    'page callback' => '\XXX\Controllers\MyurlController::indexAction',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

When I call it from the main domain, no problem. But when I call it from a subdomain, I have a 404.
mydomain.fr/fr/my-url is working
subdomain.mydomain.fr/fr/my-url doesn't work.

Same thing for /admin or /login. It works on domain but not in subdomain.

Would anyone know why and how to correct?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have $base_url set in your settings.php or other files loaded by settings.php?

Comment: Thanks for answer. But yesterday I found, it was more stupid...


the first dev did a hook in theme. And with a side effect, since some days, this hook did a bad things now. I had to change it.


If I have to give an advice for people, like me, who read this post, I found this when I searched "page_callback" in the core.